# Unable to bind datatable data to the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

ASP.NET using C#.NET; 3.5f/w

Hi,
I've a datatable as follows:

```
Location   Dotnet  Java  Others  Total
Hyd          20     25   10       55
Blore        40     30   10       80
Hyd          65     15   05       85
Hyd          20     20   10       55
```

I want to set the column headers Location, Dotnet, java, others, Total as above table to the gridview column headers.

In the above table, in the place of numeric values as shown i have textboxes in the grid.

I want to bind my data of datatable to the gridview.

My problem is unable to bind the data to the gridview since eventhough my datatable is ready.

Getting Exception:

> System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
>     Message="DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Skill1_value'."
>     Source="System.Web"
>     ErrorCode=-2147467259
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName)
>          at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String[] expressionParts)
>          at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String expression)
>          at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.Eval(String expression)
>          at ASP.location_aspx._*DataBinding*_control53(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\ABC\Location.aspx:line 250
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
>     InnerException:

Kindly help int his regard.

Pls help how to bind the datatable data to the gridview.

HTML content in sourceview:

```
                       <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                    <td style="width: 25%">
                                    <asp:TextBox  ID="txt_Skill1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Skill1_value") %>'
                                            CssClass="tms-secondaryRowTextBoxNew" Width="35%" />                                           
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
```

Here i'm not getting how to use **Skill_Value**  in  `'<%# Eval("Skill1_value") %>'` and not getting how to set a value to this textbox control from codebehind.

My problem is not getting how to bind a datatable data to gridview.

Comment: could you please show us the class/location where the error happens?

Comment: It seems like in your aspx markup you have mentioned some column 'Skill' something... It will help if you post your aspx markup

Answer (score 0):

In error code it is showing that

```
'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Skill1_value'
```

try checking that Skill1_value column is there or not.

If column name is correct then use Bind instead of eval.

You can check use of bind and eval in below given link

http://alexandershapovalov.com/eval-vs-bind-for-aspnet-46/

Contact if you have any doubt.

Comment: not in code behind Im asking about the table which you assign as datasource to the grid. There you find the column.